# WhatsApp application font

Tags: macos, applications, big-sur, font

I don't know if I'm asking my Q in the right place.
But, I recently installed a bunch of fonts on my Mac (v 11.6) and the font of my WhatsApp application (installed from App Store) changed and it's really useless and hard to read. How can I reset the font to its default?
[image: WhatsApp font changed]

Comment: How did you install the fonts, which fonts did you install? Can you add a screenshot of WhatsApp?

Comment: Actually I installed them by using "drag & drop". I'm adding a screenshot in the original post.

Comment: RE: "How can I reset the font to its default? " --  Remove the _fonts_ you installed.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for other ways. The Q is how WhatsApp changed its font on its own? OK, if I ever want to remove all the fonts, there are apple's default fonts there as well. How to know which font I've installed? If I select all of them, am I allowed by the OS to remove default fonts? If the answer is no, I have an easy way ahead...

Comment: From where to where did you drag&drop the fonts? Which specific fonts did you install?

Comment: Also, does the WhatsApp app offer a way to change fonts in its preferences?

Comment: I don't have **WhatsApp** so I don't know how its _font_ changed unless there is a way to do so in its _preferences_. That said, removing the _fonts_ you installed, if only temporarily, would allow you to see if that was the root cause. Where did you install the _fonts_ to, what _folder_, where? In **Finder** in _list view_ you can add the **Date Added** column to help you determine which _fonts_ you installed, if you can remember which ones you installed. After removing just the _fonts_  you recently installed I'd reboot the system.